# C++ string number of occurence

Tags: c++, string, char

This is my first time asking something on stackoverflow, so I'm sorry if I fail in any aspect of building the topic etc...

So I'm a newbie at C++, I'm still at the beginning. I'm using a guide someone recommended me, and I'm stuck in a exercise which is about char and strings.

It's the following: They ask me to create a function that says the number of times that a certain word was repeated on a string.

I'll leave my code below for someone who can help me, if possible dont give me an obvious response like the code and then I just copy paste it. If you can just give me some hints on how to do it, I want to try to solve it on my own. Have a good night everyone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50
using namespace std;

int times_occ(string s, string k) {
  int count = 0, i = 0;
  char word[sizeof(s)];
  // while (s[i] == k[i])
  //    {
  //        i++;
  //        if (s[i] == '\0')
  //        {
  //            break;
  //        }
  //    }
  for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(s); i++) {
    if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }
    word[i] = s[i];
  }
  word[i] = '\0';
  for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(k); i++) {
    if (word) {
      if (k[i] == word[a]) {
        a++;
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << word << endl;
  cout << count << endl;  // this was supposed to count the number of times
                          // certain word was said in a string.
  return count;
}
int main() {
  char phrase[MAX];
  char phrase1[MAX];
  cin.getline(phrase, MAX);
  cin.getline(phrase, MAX);
  times_occ(phrase, phrase1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is designed to ask and answer specific questions. Does your code do what it is supposed to when you run it? If so and you want feedback of how to improve it, then you should post on [CodeReview.SE]. If there is an error or the output is not what you want, then you should provide more information explaining what happens when you compile and run your program and what you want it to do differently. As you learn to write code, you need to learn how to debug it, too. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips.

Comment: The main thing I would recommend is to use `std::string` instead of character arrays

Comment: @AndyG They're learning. This isn't production code. It's for learning purposes. Stop telling people to use libraries when clearly they are trying to learn the basics of the language. Managing `char` arrays is part of that.

Comment: One thing: `string s;` and `for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(s); i++)` will be catastrophic since `sizeof(s)` is not the length of the string, but the size of the string object. It allocates dynamic memory "elsewhere" (probably on the heap). Use `s.size()` instead

Comment: @reakskill Define what is word. Can it be a "sub-word" of another word?

Comment: @MPops: When I was just starting out as a programmer a long time ago, there was no stackoverflow and my teachers never taught me that the STL existed (heck it had just barely been invented). I would have given my left arm to have learned about `std::vector` at least one year earlier than I did. My point is that I wish someone would have told me about it sooner, and perhaps I can do that service for someone else.  At this time of writing, OP has not indicated they know what `std::string` is. In fact, they've indicated that perhaps the opposite is true.

Comment: @MPops -- Usage of `std::string` is not "advanced".  Even the creator of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup, advocates usage of `std::string`.  [See his paper on this](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf)

Comment: @AndyG I guess, the OP didn't specify that it was for a class (where `string` is often banned from hw assignments). It's just always frustrating seeing comments like "use vectors, use <insert library that was implemented already>" when the question is clearly about learning core programming concepts, not about learning various libraries.

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(std::string)` returns the size of the `std::string` data structure, not the size of the text.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first of all, the way you've used `sizeof` isn't really valid.

`sizeof` won't tell you the length of a string. For that, you want `std::string::size()` instead.

In this case, `std::string` is an object of some class, and `sizeof` will tell you the size of an object of that class. Every object of that type will yield the same size, regardless of the length of the string.

For example, consider code like this:

```
std::string foo("123456789");
std::string bar("12345");

std::cout << sizeof(foo) << "\t" << foo.size() << "\n";
std::cout << sizeof(bar) << "\t" << bar.size() << "\n";
```

When I run this, I get output like this:

```
8   9
8   5
```

So on this implementation, `sizeof(string)` is always 8, but `some_string.size()` tells us the actual length of the string.

So, that should at least be enough to get you started moving in a useful direction.

Answer (score 0):

As @JerryCoffin mentioned, your `word` array has an invalid size. But - I want to make a more fundamental point:

Your code has two loops and a bunch of variables with arbitrary names. How should I know what's the difference between `s` and `k`? I even get `k` and `i` mixed up in the sense of forgetting that `k` is a string, not an integer. That kind of code difficult to read, and to debug. And we are a bit lazy and don't like debugging other people's code...

I suggest that you:

- Have a very clear idea what your loops do, or what the different parts of your function do.
- Create small self-contained functions - no more than one loop each please! - for each of those parts.
- Use meaningful names for each function's parameters and for the local variables.

And then, if your program doesn't work - try debugging one function at a time.